# Organ of ingestion in lice

Tags: zoology, entomology, homework, food, nutrition

I want to know that what the name of the organ used by lice for ingestion is? (also please explain if possible). In my research, I got this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_feeding_behaviours) page that didn't help me out. Then I found this [link](http://liceworld.com/how-do-head-lice-eat/) which says that it sucks blood and pumps up that with a tube so, I want the specific name of that organ.

Comment: What louse are you interested in? Human head louse? Louse is a pretty big taxon/group.

Comment: human head lice @Tytoalba

Comment: Okay. Can you do some research specifically on it? A good set of keywords would be *'head louse feeding'*. If you don't find your answer and share the things you found, your question is likely to be reopened for answering.

Comment: new edits up in the discription, you must check that out @Tytoalba